# laravel toggle button not sending value back to db ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, laravel

I'm using Laravel and ajax for the sending of request to update db. When 'is_active' has value of 1, toggle the checkbox will update the value of 'is_active' in db, but when 'is_active' has value of 1, toggle the checkbox will **NOT** update the value of 'is_active' in db. Besides that, I'm having trouble to retrieve the value of 'is_active' based on the id. And also why is my 'cancel' button not working? Did i miss out anything?

This is how my html looks like:-

```
@foreach($system_functions as $function)
     @if($function->group_id == 1)
       <input type="hidden" id="id" value="{{$function->id}}" />
          <tr>
              <td>{!! $function->name !!}</td>
              <td><input class="toggle_status" type="checkbox" @if($function->is_active) checked @endif id="is_active" name="is_active" data-on="启用" data-off="禁用" value="{{$function->id}}" data-toggle="toggle"></td>
          </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This is my js in the html file:-

```
@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggle_status').change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var is_active = 0;
            var id = $(this).attr('value');


            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                is_active = 1;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: '/admin/system-functions',
                data: {
                    is_active: is_active,
                    id:  id
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.confirm({
                        title:'edit?',
                        content:'edit?',
                        buttons:{
                            confirm: {
                                text: 'edit',
                                btnClass: 'btn-danger',
                                action: function () {
                                    $.alert(data['success']);
                                }
                            },
                            cancel: {
                                text: 'cancel',
                                btnClass: 'btn-default'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

this is my controller file

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $function=SystemFunction::where('id',$id)->first();
    if($request->get('is_active')==='on'){
        $is_active=1;
    } else{
        $is_active=0;
    }
    $function->update([
        'is_active' => $is_active
    ]);
    return response()->json(['success' => '成功修改状态']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/) to generate form inputs.

You have several mistakes, probably your problem gets solved by just fixing the first point, but you should check all of them.

**Wrong expected value inside the controller:**
In your `jQuery` code you assign `is_active` a value of `1`, but in your controller you are checking if it is `on`. Just check against the request input, if it is 0 it will be evaluated as false.

```
if($request->get('is_active')){
    $is_active=1;
} else{
    $is_active=0;
}
```

Or just:

```
$is_active = $request->get('is_active');
```

**Repeated input IDs:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="{{$function->id}}" />
<input class="toggle_status" type="checkbox" @if($function->is_active) checked @endif id="is_active" name="is_active" data-on="启用" data-off="禁用" value="{{$function->id}}" data-toggle="toggle">
```

Those inputs are inside a `foreach` loop, so I assume that there are several of them. If that's correct, the you can't have the same ID twice. If you need them, then append the loop index value to them, if not, just remove them.

```
id="id{{ $loop->index }}"
id="is_active{{ $loop->index }}"
```

**Repeated names:**
Same as above, you probably have multiple `name="is_active"`. That's not an invalid HTML, but when you work with PHP you should use array names: `name="is_active[]"`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it works perfectly now, except that do you see why is the cancel button not working ? By right when user selects the cancel button, it should revert back instead of changing the value of 'is_active' still